# Redirecting Facebook/Twitter/Google Spiders with web.config to a folder with a php script

Tags: php, redirect, iis, web-config, web-crawler

I am running an Angular application that does not play well with web spiders. So I am instead going to redirect all spiders to a php page that renders the meta data on the server side.

here is the rule I have, it almost works. But I get

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"
```

this is probably because the redirect does not work as it should. 
Here is my web.config

```
    <rule name="Spider Redirect">
      <match url=".*"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="(MSNBot|Twitterbot|Pinterest)"/>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.org/bot/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
```

So basically I want

https://example.net/post/image/123456/text

to redirect to

https://example.net/bot/post/image/123456/text

When twitter/facebook/etc crawls the site.

Any suggestions? perhaps a better way to do this?

EDIT: 
If I go to https://example.net/bot/ and fake my user agent to be MSNBot, I am redirected to https://example.net/bot/bot/.. This might be the problem, or a problem. Not sure how to solve though..